# SQLite or Internal storage for RSS on Android?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, offline-mode

I'm making an app that needs to be able to read an RSS feed offline. I've been told to get it done the most efficient way, which is either by storing the feed in a SQLite database or by storing the feed as an xml file in internal storage. Which would be more efficient, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an application that store rss feeds in a SQLite database and it's ok. Consider that if you save the .xml file you have to parse it every time for example when you want to show your rss feed into a list.

If you have already stored the feeds inside the database you can simply build a cursor adapter to adapt the data inside the database to your list, without the parsing (that it's not the simplest and nicest thing in the world).

Comment: So the database only has to parse when you're updating the data you have, but using xml on the phone means it has to parse when it updates and when it displays the list?

Comment: if you have a xml, you have to parse it in order to extract the information, both if it's on the server or it's on the phone, so yes.